# Video Sharing on facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to share image and video on face book wall using sdk.

I use following code to share image

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Classic-Guitar.jpg"];
photo.userGenerated = YES;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
```

content.photos = @[photo];

```
FBSDKShareDialog *shareCodeDialog;
shareCodeDialog = [FBSDKShareDialog new];
[shareCodeDialog setDelegate:self];
[shareCodeDialog setShareContent:content];
[shareCodeDialog setFromViewController:self];
[shareCodeDialog show];
```

Using this code i am able to post image on wall, but while sending video i am using following code

```
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSAiSTkVMfs"] absoluteURL];
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = videoURL;
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
content.video = video;


FBSDKShareDialog *shareCodeDialog;
shareCodeDialog = [FBSDKShareDialog new];
[shareCodeDialog setDelegate:self];
[shareCodeDialog setShareContent:content];
[shareCodeDialog setFromViewController:self];
[shareCodeDialog show];
```

but it not getting posted gives and error in delegate saying
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 2.)" UserInfo=0x16d95990 {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentValueKey=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSAiSTkVMfs, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=videoURL, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid value for videoURL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSAiSTkVMfs}

Answer (score 1):

The `videoURL` property has to be an asset URL (one you get from UIImagePickerController) and not a local file URL/web URL (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#videos)

If you want to share a YouTube video (or any video available on a website), use `FBSDKShareLinkContent` instead (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#links)